# Help with GRASS V.Net.Path

Tags: grass-gis, network

GRASS has extensive and brilliant documentation, but I still have a bit of trouble using v.net.path. in the example for shortest path, it says: "

```
#Shortest path: ID as first number, then cat1 and cat2

echo "1 1 2" | v.net.path myroads_net_time alayer=3 nlayer=2 out=mypath"
```

I've had trouble understanding what ID is; my table has 'cat' as it's primary key, but there is no ID column.

Any ideas?

P.S. I'm using Grass 6.4 on Mac.

Comment: Please post which GRASS GIS version you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the "ID" (as first number) defines the ID of the shortest path to be calculated. This is followed by "cat1" and "cat2" of the nodes to be connected.